# Es posible crear una aplicación que trabaje temporalmente sin conexión con Django

Tags: django

Existen ocaciones donde un cliente pierde su conexión a internet y no puede seguir realizado transacción de datos, como es conocido el trabajo sin conexión ya existe en distintas plataformas.

Necesito poder generar esto en una aplicación desarrollada en Django

Agradezco la información que me puedan brindar sobre este tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pudieras pensar la app en dos partes: en un backend con servicios mediante APIS y un frontend con cualquier [Single Page App](https://medium.com/@programacionjje/que-es-spa-single-page-application-4dbd3694fac9) o [WPA](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/?hl=es) lo cual se descargaría al cargar la app en el navegador del client. Luego de esto solo debes desarrollar la app del tal modo que persista los datos localmente usando [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) del navegador cuando no tengas conexión y en la o las DB cuando vuelva a tener conexión.

Esto es a groso modo una idea para resolver el problema en cuestión, pero al menos tienes algo por lo que empezar.

Saludos